# Simpler proof of `0<a -> 1<a+1`

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I want to know a shorter or simpler proof of the statement `forall a:nat, 0 < a -> 1 < a + 1`.
in mathcomp/ssreflect.

I have the following proof but expect the existence of more elegant one.

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.
Goal forall a:nat, 0 < a -> 1 < a + 1.
  move=>a.
  have H:1=0+1 by [].
  by rewrite {2}H ltn_add2r.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this one:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.
Goal forall a:nat, 0 < a -> 1 < a + 1.
by move=>?; rewrite addn1 ltnS.
Qed.
```

Comment: `by move=>?; rewrite (ltn_add2r 1 0).` also works. Or even `ltn_add2r _ 0`.

Comment: Thanks! Both Arthur's and Bubbler's answers work and helpful.

Comment: Another choice `by case=> // n; rewrite addn1.`